# How to resync git with svn tree?

Tags: svn, git, git-svn, rebase, git-rebase

**Background**

I'm adding some features to a project that uses subversion - I'm using git-svn to clone it to my local repository, git-svn rebase to keep with the recent changes in the official trunk and keep the history linear.

Recently I've forgot myself and made a few merges which messed my rebasing - long story short I needed to spend some time with cherry-pick to make the history linear again. After that 1 rebase went fine, but now trying to make git-svn rebase shows conflict between subversion commits from 2008 (about 700 commits back) even though history seems to be linear.

**Question**

1. Is there a way to rebuild / resync my git repository with svn trunk?
2. If I clone my git repository on a different computer (without .git/svn folder) - is it possible to rebase it with the svn, knowing the repo url and last rebased revision?

Comment: if the remote doesn't even use git, why bother with rebase at all? at the end of the day you will be sending them a patch, right?

Comment: @hansen - well no.. I'm not an official contributor. I'm hosting my changes on github. Sometimes I just send them a message with what I've changed and where they can get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reset your branch to a commit that is definitely sync-ed (some old one) and then do a rebase to synchronize.

To save the changes made locally, you might want to branch before (and cherry-pick the necessary changes from this new branch afterwatds)

```
git branch branch_with_my_changes
git reset --hard very_old_commit_that_is_synced
git svn rebase
```